# Existe algún servicio que me indique el nombre de todos los los paquetes de los navegadores predeterminados en moviles y tablets Android?

Tags: android, api, webservice

Por ejemplo en los dispositivos móviles y tablets de Samsung veo que el nombre del paquete para su navegador predeterminado es com.sec.android.app.sbrowser, quisiera conocer el de todos ya que al parecer cambia según la marca del mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podés usar `queryIntentActivities` de `PackageManager` para obtener todos los paquetes de las apps que pueden abrir una web.

```
List<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();

Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getPackageManager()
    .queryIntentActivities(webIntent, 0);

for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {
    packages.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
}
```

Comment: Interesante obtener las aplicaciones que pueden abrir el intent especificado, gracias por la aportación!+unu